# Map route to to index action in .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How do I map unmatched routes to the index action for that controller?

I'm using a client side router for routes like `/Home/foo`

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Test",
    url: "{controller}/{*.}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

This currently results in a 404.

Comment: can you show RouteConfig?

Comment: There are a few possible solutions but I like writing custom middleware for this kind of thing.  For .net core, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware

Comment: What version of MVC are you on?

Comment: @billybob MVC 5

Comment: @nurdyguy I see. What about .net MVC? :)

Comment: @Usman Which config are you referring to?

Comment: RouteConfig the file in which you define routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route that you used is correct, the problem is the orders of the routes that need to be added in write format:

for example if you have some routes like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "PreTest",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Test",
    url: "{controller}/{*.}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

So it is always matched with first route **PreTest**. Check your routes order. It is work like a dictionary that ordered. Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#scenarios_when_routing_is_not_applied) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an [AuthorizeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) to handle your case. Then you can decorate your controller with that attribute.

Here's a small example to redirect your action base on a value in the route:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public sealed class RedirectAttribute:ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if(filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values.ContainsValue("Foo"))
        {
            //Redirect to the login for example
            UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RequestContext);
            string url = urlHelper.Action("actionName", "controllerName");
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(redirectUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's how to use it in a controller:

```
[Redirect]
public class MyCustomController : AsyncController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {                        
        return View();            
    }
    public ActionResult Foo()
    {
        //It will redirect
        return View();
    }
}
```